# How to capture console outputs in matlab?

Tags: matlab, console, output

If a MATLAB subroutine outputs a status message to the console, is there a way for me to make sure it is not displayed to save some
graphical resources?

The output is annoying and unnecessary, also I'm working via a GUI client on a remote server and my connection isn't the best.

Comment: Do you mean to the terminal? You can run matlab as `matlab >/dev/null` to redirect all its output to the depths of the abyss.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - I would have suggested the same.

Comment: Some matlab routine which I cannot directly modify (in this case it's a cubic interpolator) is outputting a message to the MATLAB command window. It's a useless message being printed 100 times and I want to stop it.

Comment: Then you might want to remove the console tag.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think it is.  Flagging.